# Understand a proof of general derivative test with Taylor-Formula.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to understand a proof of the general derivative test which states:

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is differenciable $n$ times, and let $x_0 \in]a,b[$ be point with $f^{\prime}(x_0)=0, f^{\prime\prime}(x_0)=0, ..., f^{(n-1)}(x_0)=0$ but $f^{(n)}(x_0)\neq 0$.

It follows, that:

If n is uneven, $f$ does not have a local extremum in $x_0$.

If n is even, $f$ has a local extremum in $x_0$ (maximum if $f^{(n)}(x_0)<0$ and minimum if $f^{(n)}(x_0)<0$).

$\underline{\text{Proof}}$ (From the Taylor-Formula):

$f(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n+R_n(x,x_0)$ with $\lim_{x\to x_0 }\frac{R_n(x,x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$. (Which we can assume to have been proven).

It follows, that for sufficiently small differences between $x$ and $x_0$:

$|\frac{R_n(x,x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}|<\frac{1}{2}|\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}|$ (This is the first argument I can't understand).

That's why $\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n+R_n(x,x_0)$ has the same (negative/positive) sign as $\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$ (Now I get completely lost).

With uneven n, $\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n+R_n(x,x_0)$ changes its sing in $x_0$, which is why we have no local extremum.

With even n, we have

$(x-x_0)^n \geq 0$ and therefore $f(x) \geq f(x_0)$ if $f^{(n)}(x_0)>0$ and therefore a minimum,

or $f(x) \leq f(x_0)$ if $f^{(n)}(x_0)<0$ and therefore a maximum.

Now, I'm really not sure if theres an error in the script I'm reading or if it's just me missing something, but since I can't find that proof anywhere else, I wanted to ask whether anyone has any hints or suggestions on where I could look or a direct explanation.

Comment: Writing answer, request you to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is the following : look at the definition of an extremum. A point $x_0$ is an extremum if it is either a local minimum or a local maximum.

In other words, in a very small neighbourhood around $x_0$, the quantity $f(x) - f(x_0)$ has the same sign : if it is positive, then $f(x_0)$ is a minimum(because that's the same as saying that $f(x) \geq f(x_0)$ in the neighbourhood) else it is a maximum. If one of these happens then $x_0$ is an extremum.

Therefore, to show that a point is (or is not) an extremum , one merely must study the quantity $f(x) - f(x_0)$ in a small enough neighbourhood of $x_0$. We must essentially study the sign of $f(x) - f(x_0)$ : if it changes sign, then $f(x_0)$ is not an extremum. If it doesn't change sign, then depending upon which sign it takes we'd have a local minimum or maximum.

And so, on to the study of $f(x) - f(x_0)$.

---

You have mentioned that you know Taylor's theorem. Therefore, under the given conditions on the derivatives, if I write the expansion $f(x) = f(x_0) + \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0) + R_n(x,x_0)$  you should be comfortable with each of the terms, and acknowledge the fact that $\lim_{x  \to x_0} \frac{R_n(x,x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n} = 0$.

Therefore, $f(x) - f(x_0) = \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n + R_n(x,x_0)$. The left hand side is what we want to study : with this equality we may now study the sign changes in the right hand side!

For convenience, let us perform the following rewrite of the right hand side:
$$
\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n + R_n(x,x_0) = (x-x_0)^n\left(\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}+\frac{R_n(x,x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}\right)
$$

The sign of the product, is the product of the signs! Therefore, we are restricted to the study of the sign of the two quantities on the right hand side.

---

For $(x-x_0)^n$, we note that the sign depends upon two things : if $n$ is even , then this is positive always. If $n$ is odd, then this is positive if and only if $x> x_0$. To finish analysis, note that in any neighbourhood of $x_0$, there's always a point which is bigger than $x_0$ : so conclusion would be "if $n$ is odd, there's a sign change of this expression : but if $n$ is even, there's no sign change".

---

For the other, we note that $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{R_n(x,x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$ by the Taylor expansion. Adding the $f^{(n)}$ part in (it's just a constant depending on $x_0$) we get :
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!} + \frac{R_n(x,x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n} = \frac{f^n(x_0)}{n!}
$$

So we have a limit. Which is excellent, and you'll see why.

In your head, imagine a wild sequence, but still one converging to a positive number, say $0.01$. Can you prove rigorously why it must be positive after some time?

The answer would roughly be this : if the sequence is converging to $0.01$, then we can ensure the sequence goes as close to $0.01$ as we want, by going as far up the sequence as required! Now, if the sequence is very very close to $0.01$, then certainly it must continue to have *positive* terms, because you dragged it this side of $0$ by going far enough up the sequence.

The same thing happens here : note that $\frac{f^n(x_0)}{n!}$ is not zero, so has a sign. The limit ensures that the quantity , whose limit is being taken, will also get the same sign if we take large enough $N$.

The proof of this fact, I leave you to decipher from either the other answer or by the explanation. Or fine, take $\epsilon = \frac 12\left|\frac{f^{(n)}}{(x-x_0)^n}\right|$ then see what you get in the definition of limit existing.

To conclude, the second quantity we wanted to study will take on the same sign as $f^{n}(x_0)$ (since $n!$ is always positive) in a small enough neighbourhood of $x_0$. So it won't change sign!

---

And now we can finish :

- If $n$ is odd, then the first quantity changes sign but the second doesn't : this means in total there is a sign change at $x_0$, so $x_0$ is not an extremum.
- If $n$ is even, then neither quantity changes sign , so $f(x) -f(x_0)$ doesn't change sign, giving that $x_0$ is an extremum. Of course, then $f(x) -f(x_0)$ has the same sign as $f^{(n)}(x_0)$: so if $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ is positive, this is positive and we have a minima. Else, we have a maxima!

Comment: Thank you so much, great, well written and comprehensible answer. Really nice of you for taking the time.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{R_n(x,x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}=0$$
means that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 $ so that $|x-x_0|<\delta \implies \left|\frac{R_n(x,x_0)}{(x-x_0)^n}\right|<\varepsilon$. So you just need to pick the appropriate $\varepsilon$. And from this, we have that
$$|R_n(x,x_0)|<\varepsilon|x-x_0|^n$$
Can you continue now?