# How can one determine if there is a local extremum at some point on a function if the first and second derivatives are both 0?

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

It is known that in order to find the local extrema of a function, one must find its critical points (where the derivative is zero or undefined), followed by which one would substitute these values into the function's second derivative and if it's positive, it's a local minimum, and if it's negative, it's a local maximum.

But what if the second derivative is equal to zero? How are the local extrema evaluated then? Must we take the third derivative, or is it something simpler I'm missing?

A further sub-question is about how to determine if a point on a function is a local extremum if all derivatives at that point are undefined. For example, the one local (and absolute) minimum of $f(x) = |x|$ is obviously $(0,0)$, but how would one prove this algebraically, considering that $f^{(n)}(x)$ does not exist?

Comment: One way is to test if the first derivative changes sign across your critical point. If it does, there's a max/min, if not there isn't. I'm assuming all this is in one dimension BTW.

Comment: I suppose then that I would use test points approaching the critical points, and determine if the first derivative changes sign? I think that clears up my question.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Though in theory you have to be careful that your critical point is isolated (if there's a bunch of critical points arbitrarily close to it, then there might be no notion of "change sign across").

Comment: There may be an extrema at $x$, even though the derivative does not make a "change of sign across $x$".

Comment: If $f$ is nice enough, you can use the Taylor expansion. Like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3334616/understand-a-proof-of-general-derivative-test-with-taylor-formula

Comment: @DavidMitra: If the critical point is isolated (meaning it's the only point with zero derivative in some open neighborhood of it), how could we get an extremum if $f$ is, say, increasing on both sides of it?

Comment: @Jose27 Ohh, I missed seeing the isolated condition.